# Is the map $h(m)=(rm_1,m_2)$ a homothety of $M=M_1\bigoplus M_2$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring,  $M=M_1\bigoplus M_2$ be a left $R$-module and $f:M_1\to M_1,m_1\mapsto rm_1$ be a homothety of $M_1$, then the map  $h(m)=(rm_1,m_2)$  is a module endomorphism of $M$.

My question:  Is $h$ a homothety of $M$?  Is it possible to consider $h$ as $h(m)=(f(m_1),m_2)=(rm_1,m_2)=r(m_1,m_2)=rm$?   I know it is not a restriction to $M_1$.

Comment: It is a $R\times R$-module homothety, but not a $R$-module homothety unless $r-1\in Ann_R(M_1)$.

Comment: Okay! I have got it, thank you!